# Approach to creating a Socket.IO on Android application that has a Node.JS webserver

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, web, socket.io

I have a webserver that is written in Node.JS with socket.io.

It contains a JSON api which allows my Android app to grab JSON data from the server and render it in the Application.

However, it can only do it static right now. It has no way of detecting real-time changes in the server that will update the view in realtime in the APP without restarting the APP.

The website version is working perfectly, where I was able to use socket.on and socket.emit on both the server side and client side to get changes on the and update it on the website.

But how do I have the socket working on the Android App?

Pointing me to the right direction would appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the server is in Socket.io, You have to use a Java client for Socket.io in your Android app,   I have used the [Gottox Java client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) for Socket.io, which is pretty straightforward.  Have a look at the example.

Updating your views does not require your app to restart. You have to implement proper android logic for that.

Comment: So do I use it as a intermediary between the Android App to the Web Service? Also, where can I host this on the cloud?

Comment: Did you see the example? Anyway, it is a Java implementation of the socket.io client. It performs all the operations that the Javascript client does on the web browser. You can receive the server event and also emit the event from your device.